# Upgrade from 12.04 to 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, updates

I have installed a new VM and the template that provider has is only for 12.04.
How can I update to 12.04.3 (and be safe not to upgrade to 12.10).
I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but it says nothing to update.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing to update you are already using 12.04.3.

Point releases incluide secutiry and software updates after a certain period of time so you don't need to install gazillion of updates since the first time if was released.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: uname -a shows it to be 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
lsb_release -a
```

This should tell you in the description that you are running 12.04.3 already (to put your mind at ease). The release is still called 12.04 which is why you see that in the system details.

Comment: I tried, it still shows 12.04 and even the kernel version is 3.2

Comment: Here is what I get in output

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Comment: Try opening the `software sources` window and checking that the (main) and (universe) repositories are on. Then go to the updates tab and check that (precise-security) and (precise-updates) are on.